# MS Access: How to disable Form autosave and create Save button

Tags: ms-access, autosave

I understand that inputting data in a form in MS Access automatically updates the fields in the table. However, how do I disable this feature and instead allow a user to click a "Save" button at the end to update the records? Have been reading online that I need VBA etc. that I have no experience with.

Answer (score 3):

This can only be done in code.

You need to set a module level boolean variable to control saving (auto vs manual) and set its value to True when the save button is clicked.

```
Private mIsUserUpdate As Boolean 'Flag

'Cancel Auto Save
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not mIsUserUpdate Then Cancel = True
End Sub

'Manual Save
Private Sub YourButtonName_Click()

    '...
    'Do work
    '...

    mIsUserUpdate = True 'OK to save
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    mIsUserUpdate = False 'Revert
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe Me.Undo instead of Cancel = True

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot disable autosaving in forms. As a workaround you can copy data to temporary table, allow user to edit the data as needed and by clicking "Save" button copy changed data back to main table.

Also as a workaround can be used canceling record saving as it described in the answer of @Kostas K. within one form, but in this case you won't be able to change edited record or use any controls outside of edit form if it is a subform, so Save button should be located on the same form as edited data.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use a pair of text boxes. One is bound to the database and the other is not. The bound text box would not be visible.

```
Text1 is not bound
Text2 is bound
```

Code for the save button..

```
Me.Text2.value = me.Text1.value
if me.dirty=true then me.dirty=false
```

You can get into specific conditions...

```
If isnull(me.Text1.value) then me.Text2=.value=""
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many ways. Answer by "Kostas K" is OK. But if you accidentally or intentionally edit a field, then you can't use the navigation buttons. You can't go Next or Previous records unless you enter into Edit mode (set the flag variable to True).
For me below code works better. If you want to edit a record, click Edit button. After editing you can use the manual Save button or use navigation button to save your record.

```
Dim update As Boolean

Private Sub cmdedit_Click()
    update = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdsave_Click()
    'Your commands or ...
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    If update = False Then Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    update = False
End Sub
```

Comment: @Maëlan I have included the author's name.