# Requiring two fields to both be empty or both be filled

Tags: ms-access

Is there any way to do this in MS Access? I created a form based on the table, and due to the type of data I am dealing with, two certain fields should either both be empty or both be nonempty. Right now the user can fill in one and not the other, which is what I want to prevent. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the form bound or unbound?

Comment: It is a bound form

Comment: You can do custom validation in the form's BeforeUpdate event. Is that enough information or would you like the code as well?

Comment: Having the code would be helpful if it's not too much of a hassle. I'm not a big SQL expert, and the database isn't super in-depth so I've been getting by without it so far.

Comment: You need to cancel the auto-update, do your validation and save manually if all is in order. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401614/ms-access-how-to-disable-form-autosave-and-create-save-button/44404185#44404185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know the names of your fields, but you can replace FIELD1 and FIELD2 with their names and use this code in the `BeforeUpdate` event.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If (isnull(FIELD1) and not isnull(FIELD2)) OR (isnull(FIELD2) and not isnull(FIELD1)) Then 
      Cancel=True
      MsgBox("Data not saved.")
    End If
End Sub
```